# How do I get the zlib library and headers?

Tags: zlib

I want to install a program from a tar.gz file and when I write `./configure` I obtained this error:

```
 checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required
```

I tried to install a new version of zlib but that said zlib is the most recent version.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 32 bits.

Could someone help me?

Comment: What package specifically did you try to install? Do you have the zlib *development* package `zlib1g-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem.

```
$ sudo apt install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Please explain why this solves the problem (and how you found the solution)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libjpeg-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

You will likely require jpeg as well as zlib library and header